# copy WSL instance from one machine to another

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

So I recently got a new laptop and wanted to move my WSL files from the old machine to the new machine. Like an idiot, I literally just copied the filesystem 
(C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Packages\CanonicalReallyLongDirectoryNameHere\LocalState\rootfs)

from the old machine to the new machine after installing WSL on the new machine.

Now WSL won't start on the new machine. I've tried to uninstall and reinstall WSL on the new machine but I've discovered that `lxrun` is deprecated, and I can't find an article with clear instructions on how to uninstall/reinstall without `lxrun`. I've looked at this guy:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/reference

but what's the difference between unregister and terminate? The documentation isn't very clear on what exactly these commands do and what the differences are between them.

EDIT: I found that you can go into Settings > Apps and Features > Ubuntu [release] > advanced options > reset

and that got WSL running again on my machine.

For progeny's sake, is there anyway to easily copy one WSL instance to another? I've seen in the above referenced documentation that there's now a command to import and export WSL distros; do these operations preserve all the applications that may have been installed? For code, it'd be easy enough to just copy the 'home' directory from one instance to another and that shouldn't break anything, but I don't want to have to reinstall all my applications again.

EDIT 2:

So I found this article:

https://www.howtogeek.com/426562/how-to-export-and-import-your-linux-systems-on-windows-10/

That says you can run `wsl --export distro_name filename.tar` to export your filesystem, but when I try that on my old machine, it just spits out the usage information for wsl.exe:

```
Usage: wsl.exe [option] ...
Options:
-d, --distribution <DistributionName>
    Launch the specified distribition.

-e, --exec <CommandLine>
    Execute the specified Linux command. The remainder of the arguments are
    used as the command line to execute.

-u, --user <UserName>
    Run as the specified user.

--help
    Display this usage information.

--
    Stop parsing arguments and pass the remainder to the Linux process.
```

EDIT 3: Apparently in order to use the `--import` and `--export` options, you need to be on at least Windows build 1903

https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/WSL/issues/419

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: updated my question, moved the content of this answer there. Keeping this answer in order to keep comments

Comment: How did this trick "work" exactly, in the context of the original question?  It sounded like you are saying the solution was to copy over the rootfs disk to the new computer and run Advanced Options -> Reset, however that results in deleting the file you just copied (at least it did on my computer).

Comment: I just changed the wording on this answer to clarify some things. If you read my question above, you'll see where I did the "Advanced Options > Reset" between the original question and the second edit.

Answer (score -1):

I followed your original bold idea of copying the disk over and succeeded.  The flow of how I did this on WSL2 is with my new system:

1. Installed Ubuntu  (i.e., same release as the source computer).
2. Ran the Ubuntu  prompt once so that it would create its own disk image.
3. Ran an elevated command prompt, `wsl --shutdown` to stop that installed instance.
4. Copied the disk image file over as you indicated to the same location on the new system, overwriting the newly-minted disk image with the one from my old computer.
5. Opened the Ubuntu  prompt and edited `/etc/wsl.conf` to set the default user to my existing user:

   ```
   [user]
   default=<username>
   ```
6. Exited and re-opened my Ubuntu  prompt.

At that point I was logged in as my existing user and all of my files, etc. were there from the old installation.

I'm a little curious why despite copying over the rootfs as we did here *did not* also include my `/etc/wsl.conf`, which already had that setting on my old computer.